# How to handle properly the Gulp's Task function in NodeJS API?

Tags: node.js, typescript, promise, gulp, typescript-eslint

Currenly, I know only one working method of runnig the Gulp task without `gulpfile` and CLI:

```js
import Gulp from "gulp";

const TASK_NAME: string = "EXAMPLE_TASK";

Gulp.task(TASK_NAME, Gulp.parallel([
    // ... imported task fuctions ...
]);

Gulp.task(TASK_NAME)(
    (error?: Error | null): void => { if (isNeitherUndefinedNorNull(error)) { console.error(error); } }
);
```

It is not the subject of question; I just explained what I doing and why my code is such as, but if you know
the better method of executing of Gulp task without `gulpfile` and CLI, please let me now.

Now about the subject. Until recently, the last part of the code (`Gulp.task(TASK_NAME)(/* ... */)`)
has not been rejected by [no-floating-promises](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/no-floating-promises.md) rule if [typescript-eslint](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint). By after latest update of `@types/gulp` (or `typescript-eslint` - now it's hard to explore which one)
`typescript-eslint` warn me:

> Promises must be handled appropriately or explicitly marked as ignored with the `void` operator

there. I know it's not the false alarm. Sometimes my Gulp tasks chain broken with `unhandled promise rejection`, but it was not obvious where promise was. Now I had the hint, but it's still unclear.

I explored that:

1. `Gulp.task()` returned the `Undertaker.TaskFunctionWrapped`
2. `TaskFunctionWrapped` extends the `TaskFunctionBase`
3. `TaskFunctionBase` is `(done: TaskCallback): ReturnType<AsyncTask>;`
4. The `AsyncTask` is:

```js
export type AsyncTask<R = any> =
  ((done: VoidCallback) => void)
  | ((done: Callback<R>) => void)
  | (() => ChildProcess | EventEmitter | Observable<R> | PromiseLike<R> | Stream);
```

According [documentation](https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/getting-started/async-completion), the task function must return the `ChildProcess`, `EventEmitter` , `Observable`, `Promise` or `Stream`. But how to handle it? `Gult.task()()` is not thenable:

[image]

Error texting:

> TS2339: Property 'catch' does not exist on type 'void | EventEmitter | ChildProcess | Stream | Observable | PromiseLike'.

### Update: @TheBumpaster solution try

Unfortunately, the @typescript/eslint still tells me "Promises must be handled appropriately or explicitly marked as ignored with the `void` operator" in `Gulp.task(ProjectBuilder.GULP_TASK_NAME)` line.

```js
const task: Promise<void> = new Promise<void>((resolve: () => void, reject: (error: Error) => void): void => {

  console.log("checkpoint1");

  Gulp.task(ProjectBuilder.GULP_TASK_NAME)(
      (error?: Error | null): void => {

        if (isNeitherUndefinedNorNull(error)) {
          console.log("checkpoint2-A");
          reject(error);
        } else {
          console.log("checkpoint2-B");
          resolve();
        }
      }
  );
});

task.catch((error: Error): void => { console.error(error); });
```

I intentionally rise the error in some of gulp plugins. The project builder reaches the `"checkpoint1"` but neither `"checkpoint2-A"` nor `"checkpoint2-B"`. The output is:

```
D:\XXX\node_modules\async-done\index.js:18
    throw err;
    ^

Error [ERR_UNHANDLED_ERROR]: Unhandled error. ({
  uid: 0,
  name: '<anonymous>',
  branch: false,
  error: AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]:
```

Maybe it's indirectly indicates that @typescript/eslint yelling is not a lip service...

Answer (score 1):

You should have been aware of the fact that handling promises are required for 'catch' function.

According to https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/getting-started/async-completion/

```
Gulp.Task(ProjectBuilder.GLUP_TASK_NAME)( (error) => { if ( error ) { 
  throw new Error(error); } // this is already executed 
 }
```

---

```
const task = new Promise( (resolve, reject ) => {

Gulp.Task(ProjectBuilder.GLUP_TASK_NAME)( (error) => { if ( error ) { reject(error) } resolve() }

});

task().then().catch(e => console.error(e))
```

Update on comment:

Perhaps this example might help you demonstrate what have I meant with my code above.

```
const gulp = require("gulp")
const taskName = "task-name"

// Example callback
gulp.task(taskName, (error) => {
    if (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
    // It's already executed here
    console.log(taskName)
});

// Example Promise object
const Task = new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
    gulp.task(taskName, (error) => {
        if (error) {
            reject(error)
        }
        resolve(taskName)
    });
});

Task.then(console.log).catch(console.error)

// Example Promise function
const performTask = (_taskName) => {
    return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
        gulp.task(_taskName, (error) => {
            if (error) {
                reject(error)
            }
            resolve(_taskName)
        });
    });
}

performTask(taskName).then(console.log).catch(console.error)


// Example async/await with then/catch
const exampleServiceHandler = async (_taskName) => {
    // Perform actions here
    try {
        return await gulp.task(_taskName) // Resolve the task
    } catch (exception) {
        return exception;
    }
}

exampleServiceHandler(taskName)
.then(console.log)
.catch(console.error)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Sorry about checked it too late. I'm afraid, the `task()` is not callable in your code. Did you mean returning of `Gulp.Task(ProjectBuilder.GLUP_TASK_NAME)(..)`? If so, no `{}` must be.

Comment: Gulp is a namespace, Task is a class function. What you refer to {} is from callback function block.. perhaps you are expecting that Gulp.Task handles a promise, but that will not happen, you need to wrap it with Promise() or use a gulp-promise library

Comment: Thank you for the support of your solution after reputation prize receiving. Unfortunately, @typescript-eslint still don't like this solution. Additionally, I make some experiment and knew what we don't reaching the `if (error) { reject() } ` when error occurs. If you please, may you check the updated question? Also, your example  commented as "Example Promise object" is pretty differs with out case. In example, we have `gulp.task(taskName, (error) => {})`, but our case is `gulp.task(taskName)((error) => {})` (the undocumented execution of gulp application without gulpfile).